# Не последует ли бан от гугла из-за редиректа?

Tags: nginx, google-chrome, http-redirect

У клиента есть домен на котором он хотел сделать лендинг с информацией о продукте, в то же время на своем продукте он выгравировал QR-код, который вел на данный домен, но в ходе роботы он решил перенести свой продукт на сервис доски объявлений (так ему показалось в разы проще), а так как QR-код напечатан, было принято решения перенаправить редиректом на страницу доскы объявления при сканировании данного QR-кода, то-есть:

```
[клиент сканирует QR-код] -> [QR-код ведет на домен mydomen.com] -> [домен спомощю nginx перенаправляет на страницу продажы на доске обявления]
```

код в nginx ничего особенного:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name mydomen.com www.mydomen.com;

    return 301 "https://страница/на/доске/обявления";
}
```

Вопрос: не последует ли бан в браузере или чего-то подобного из самой доски, за редиректы с домена который по факту не имеет отношения от сервиса на котором было выставленною объявления?

Comment: Нет, в этом нет ничего такого, напротив, это частая ситуация.

Comment: По идее не должно, если к примеру на Firefox будет редирект то сначала пользователь должен его подтвердить, но в принципе это не мешает перейти на доску объявлений, насчёт Chrome&Opera не знаю.

Comment: Перманентный редирект лучше не делать на сторонний сайт.

Comment: @Kotomi а какие последствия/причины, и как тогда правильно решить данную проблему?

Comment: 302 код отдать, но не 301.

Comment: @Kotomi ага, спасибо, я сам думал что лучше 302.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бана или пессимизации не будет если страница сайта будет перенаправлять и пользователей и роботов. Лучше использовать 301 редирект т.к. перенаправление у вас планируется быть постоянным.
И не делайте ничего что могло бы стать похожим на [дорвей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Comment: По факту самой страницы и нет на оригинальном сайте, все запросы на домен перенаправляются на конкретную страницу на сайте объявлений, я так понимаю в этому случае нет ни какова дорвея?

Comment: тогда да, дорвея нет